# Не удается перенести проект Yii на локальный сервер

Tags: yii2, yii, localhost

Переношу проект Yii на локальный сервер. Файл main.php:

```
return array(
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'Admin',

// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),

'language' => 'ua',

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.vendors.*',
    'ext.*',
    'ext.chosen.*',
    'ext.helpers.*',
),

'aliases'=>array(
    'widget'=>'application.widget',
    'widgets'=>'application.widget',
),

'defaultController'=>'request/input',

'modules'=>array(
    'admin',
    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'bukreev',
         'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),      // изменил на 127.0.0.1
         'generatorPaths'=>array(
             'application.gii',   // псевдоним пути
         ),
    ),
),


// application components
'components'=>array(
    'yexcel' => array(
        'class' => 'ext.yexcel.Yexcel'
    ),

    'image' => array(
        'class'=>'ext.image.CImageComponent',
        // GD or ImageMagick
        'driver'=>'GD',
        // ImageMagick setup path
        //'params'=>array('directory'=>"C:\ImageMagick\\"),
    ),

    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'class' => 'WebUser',
    ),

    'request' => array(
        //'enableCsrfValidation'=>true,
        //'enableCookieValidation'=>true,
    ),

    'authManager' => array(
        // Будем использовать свой менеджер авторизации
        'class' => 'PhpAuthManager',
        // Роль по умолчанию. Все, кто не админы, модераторы и юзеры — гости.
        'defaultRoles' => array('guest'),
    ),

    'epassgen' => array(
        'class' => 'ext.epasswordgenerator.EPasswordGenerator',
    ),

    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog',
         // изменил названиехоста и создал базу данных blog
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',             //поменял имя и пароль
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        //'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ),



    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),

    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),
            */
        ),
    ),
),

// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/params.php'),
```

);

Базу данных создал, пароль и имя юзера переименовал, название хоста изменил на локальный...Но все равно апач выдает такую ошибку:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2017:12:44:27 +0300] "GET /site/login HTTP/1.1" 404 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
```

А в браузере:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /site/login was not found on this server.
```

В чем  может быть загвоздка?

П.С.:

```
  сначала создал дефолтный проект   ->
  проверил его работоспособность    ->
  скопировал мой проект в дефолтный ->
  сделал базу данных blog           ->
  внес изменения в файл main.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас Apache2 проверьте есть ли в корневой директории `.htaccess` файл, по некоторым причинам файл `.htaccess` могли не перенести или он переименовался к примеру в `htaccess` или `_htaccess`

Comment: Yaroslav, стоит apache2, файл  .htaccess располагается в папке protected и гласит "deny from all"
П.С.: в дефолтном проекте .htaccess храниться там же и нормально запускается

Comment: каким образом тогда ЧПУ реализован? Если стоит apache значит через .htaccess должен настраиваться ЧПУ

Comment: в файле main.php прописан 'urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
   'showScriptName'=>false,
   'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
   ),

Comment: Это на стороне фреймворка, но нужно ещё чтобы Apache знал что запросы нужно принимать по этим правилам, сейчас он работает как я понимаю с index.php,по идее в браузере вы перейдете по ссылке /index.php?r=/site/login, а вот чтоб перешли по /site/login надо об этом сказать Apache через .htaccess файл в корне проекта.

Comment: т.е. мне нужно получается сделать еще один файл .htaccess  и разместить в корне проекта?

Comment: Да, если говорите что сайт переносите, значит он работал, а это значит что этот файл есть на хостинге или сервере

Comment: да, но меня смутило, что при установке фреймверка, дефолтного проекта, в корне проект там не лежит .htaccess

Comment: Потому что в дефолтном проекте не предусмотрено ЧПУ с убиранием index.php

Comment: разобрался, спасибо Вам огромное!